TYPO3 First Installation - 404 Page Not Found
I'm new to typo3 and I installed it today, and after the last step I picked "take me straight to the backend". So it took me to the login site ***/TYPO3/login
It says "Not Found, The requested url was not Found on this server" When I open the normal site without the login, it says "404 page not Found, the page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No site configuration found"
I can access the login page with ***/typo3/ but when I try to login I get the same error "not Found. The request url..."
Can someone help me?
I installed this on Ubuntu server with this tutorial
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-typo3-on-ubuntu-22-04/
I searched in the web for solutions but I couldn't find anything useful

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about using/configuring TYPO3, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.

Very likely you didn't copy the .htaccess file in the web-directory.
The default file can be copied from here:

in composer installations:
vendor/typo3/cms-install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess

in legacy installations (non-composer):
public/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess



Thanks for your quick answer, but I have a question. Instead of "typo3" I have TYPO3_src.tgz, it's the same right? And where exactly do I have to copy it? Where is the web-directory path?

Then you make a legacy installation and the 2nd point is for your case.
the first folder of the path can be different, it can be htdocs, public_html, html or anything else, it might be determined by your hosting company, it's called the web-root.
Keep in mind though that the sourcode (the unpacked TYPO3 package) should be above this web-root and made available in the web-root by symlinks.

The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

@Toby Speight feel free to transfer the question to another Stack Exchange platform if you know how to do it. I'm well aware of the fact that you mentioned, but also that TYPO3 is tagged here quite often, including problems that don't relate to programming. Mentioning it once below the question would be enough perhaps, but 3 times looks a bit over the top for me.

As you have added the tag "typo3-8.x" to your question we have to assume that you are trying to install TYPO3 8.x (e.g. the LTS version 8.7), based on the classic archive. This version was released in 2017, 5 years before the article linked in your question and now 7 years ago. The system requirements of that version conflict with what is described in the article. It is likely that this results in the described issue. Also this version is outside of the free and since March 2024 also outside of the commercial support window and should therefore not be used anymore.
The current version that should be used for new projects is LTS 12.4 ("stable").
It can be downloaded here: https://get.typo3.org/version/12
You'll find the current system requirements and the different ways to install TYPO3 on that page. It is recommended to use a Composer based installation instead of the classic archives.

The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.
